# send jquery object with jquery post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, post

i want to send a jquery object to a php function using post my object comes in then i stringify it and get the following output

```
[
  {
    "id": "701",
    "user_id": "2",
    "playlist": "ukg%20garage",
    "tracks": "5",
    "thumbnail": "Coldplay.jpeg",
    "createdon": "2012-08-23 16:06:46"
  }
]
```

so i then pass this thru with post as below

```
var sendData = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
console.log(sendData);
$.post('<?php echo base_url(); ?>account_media/updateplaylistpicture', sendData, function(response) {

            console.log(response);

          });
```

and with my php i am doing a print_r($_POST) but its returning nothing

```
Array
(
)
```

Where am i going wrong thanks

UPDATE I MANAGED TO SUSS IT WITH THE BELOW

```
var sendData = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
var sendData = sendData.replace(/[\[\]']+/g,'');
$.post('<?php echo base_url(); ?>account_media/updateplaylistpicture', jQuery.parseJSON(sendData), function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is very likely because the POST does not contain any "key".
Try this:

```
print_r(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Another way would be to:

```
$.post('<?php echo base_url(); ?>account_media/updateplaylistpicture', 'my_stuff=' + sendData, function(response) {

            console.log(response);

          });
```